# Does there exist a closed form solution to this function, related to the moment generating function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm wondering if similar to the multivariate moment generating function, there is a closed form solution to this function of normally distributed variables:

$f_{\mathbb{x}}(\mathbb{t})=E[\exp(x_1^{t_1} + x_2^{t_2})]$ when $ \mathbb{x} \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$

It's coming up in a model and I'm not sure if I should just approximate it, or a solution exists.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are $x_1$ and $x_2$ independent?

Comment: No, the covariance matrix is $\Sigma$, (2x2 matrix)

Comment: [This](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MTH5118/Notes11-09.pdf) will likely be helpful; see page 2.